# Regex with lazy match (for first orccurance only) in Notepad++

Tags: regex, match, notepad++

I have this regex to find all lines starting from the word "chapter" till the first blank line: `^chapter.*^\s*$`. However I want it to show the first occurrence only, so I tried adding to the end '.?' or '(.+?)'.  But I an not sure how to implement the lazy quantifier here.

Example text:

```
Chapter 1: some text
more than one line,
next line.

Chapter 2: text text text
other text

Chapter 3: more text
more lines
more lines
```

So the regex should match from the first word "Chapter " till the blank line before the next chapter.. etc.

Comment: please, show test examples - strings that should and should not be matched by the regex

Comment: added an example

Comment: You may use this regex `\AChapter.*\n(?:.*?\S.*\n)*`

Comment: I am using NP++ in Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use" `/Chapter((?!\n\n).)*/s`, on windows `Chapter((?!\R\R)(.|\R))*\R?`

- `Chapter` literal matches chapter beginning
- `((?!\n\n).)*` matches any character as long as next two characters are not newlines (due to negative lookahead `(?!\n\n)`)
- note the `s` option that makes the dot `.` match a newline; If you don't have such option in notepad++, you can use `Chapter((?!\n\n)(.|\n))*` and on windows `Chapter((?!\R\R)(.|\R))*\R?` to match the newline.

[Basic Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQXwZg/1)
[Windows demo](https://regex101.com/r/QQXwZg/3/)

Comment: I am using Notepad++, does this line needs some edit for it?

Comment: Try the second example: `Chapter((?!\n\n)(.|\n))*` and let me know if it works. I don't have notepad++ to test it.

Comment: it selects the whole document

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: this selects only the line that has the word chapter till the end of line

Comment: That's good..  can you do a final edit that makes it select until the first blank line after that? (with Chapter((?!\R\R)(.|\R))* is stops at the last character, and I need the next blank line selected too..

Comment: `Chapter((?!\R\R)(.|\R))*\R?` ?

Comment: Great.. thanks.. Please edit or add it to the answer so I accept it as the right answer.

Comment: I've added it, pls check

Comment: @Mike pls consider upvoting, if you find it helpful (actually it has more value to me than the acceptance).

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to select first set of lines starting with `Chapter`:

```
\AChapter.*\r?\n(?:.*?\S.*\r?\n)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UkUkwj/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\A`: Start anchor (matches once per document)
- `Chapter.*\r?\n`: Match text `Chapter` followed by any text till line break
- `(?:.*?\S.*\r?\n)*`:  Match 0 or more following lines containing at least one non-space character

Comment: I am trying to run this in Notepad++ under Windows.  So that command is not working with it.

Comment: [As per this doc](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) Notepad++ supports PCRE flavor so this regex should work.

Comment: You can try this regex also: `\AChapter.*\R(?:.*?\S.*\R)*`

Comment: It selects the whole document, starting from the word "chapter".

Comment: Next to the "Regular expression" selection in "Search Mode" there is a "matches newline" checkbox  Make sure that is checked